# Removing highly correlated variables in logistic regression in r

Tags: r, correlation, logistic

I am developing a logistic regression model on a large dataset consisting of 15 variables and 200k observations.
In initial model fitting, I find variables - "Purchase Frequency" and "Average Payment Amount" are highly correlated (GVIF values around 20) and both are significant in terms of p value.
When I remove one of these two variable, the other variable becomes insignificant and also few other variables (low VIF value) becomes insignificant from significant in previous case.

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: As @Alex mentioned this question is for Cross Validated. Nevertheless, to help you phrase you question better, it seems like you face problem of strong multicollinearity. You should research this topic a bit more UCLA's blog is a good read for start. http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/logistic/chapter3/statalog3.htm

Answer (score 1):

You should probably remove one of the variables (I say probably as a general case because I don't have the output - if you want a more accurate answer, post some of the residuals / results)

$p$-values aren't an 'instant win' in terms of models - having a statistically significant $p$-value on one of your variables does not guarantee that your overall model is statistically significant or useful. In fact, $p$-values can be very deceptive.

For example, consider the following simplified dataset:

```
Y   X   Z
0   1   1
0   2   2
0   3   4
0   6   6
0   9   8
0   2   2
```

You could build a 'beautiful' model with $Y = 100X - 100Z$. This model would have a great $R^2$, and really low $p$-values, but it's pretty obvious that this model isn't the best way to look at $Y$.

In the same manner, your correlated variables may be like the $X$ and $Z$ here. You should take one of them out in order to see patterns more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to proceed is to take a ratio of the two highly correlated variables. Considering your variables are `Purchase` and `Payment` related, am sure the ratio would be meaningful. This way you capture the effects of both, without bothering the other variables.
On a separate note, if the significance and/or correlation of other variables is changing on dropping a variable, you may want to take another look at the model itself.